# Switch form input animation bouncing strangely in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, reactjs

When switching between form inputs on mobile safari, the cursor animates down and bounces in a strange way (whether you're using the arrow buttons, or simply clicking the form itself)

[Here is a link to a video of the jumping in action](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/1qw4syg7vhmfatn/AACQY_6PRTZpTwyJ21elW3bXa)

Comment: Is there some code you can add to your question? I'm not sure what your question is about?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's the QuickType bar that's causing the screen to change the size of the keyboard... try adding this to your inputs.

```
<input autoCapitalize="off" autoComplete="off" autoCorrect="off" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

The soft keyboard changes the height of the screen, because when you enter the `User ID` the predictive fields are shown, conversely they are hidden when you enter the `Password` – because passwords have no suggestions.

You need to align the container of the login pane to the bottom, so when the size of the viewport changes, the container slides up – remaining aligned to the bottom – and there is no *bounce* effect.

In `css` something as:

```
.container{
    position: absolute:
    bottom: 0;
}
```